# json formatting of timestamp

Tags: mysql, json

I got an AngularJS client, nodeJS server, and a MySQL DB.

I am trying to delete an entry of a table, when timestamp is a primery key with user Email.

The JSON giving me the this data from the DB:

```
[{"instanceTime":"2018-02-10T14:19:29.000Z","item":"write papter","email":"admin@gmail.com","ischeck":0},
{"instanceTime":"2018-02-10T14:19:33.000Z","item":"paint chair","email":"admin@gmail.com","ischeck":0},
{"instanceTime":"2018-02-10T15:07:34.000Z","item":"yes","email":"admin@gmail.com","ischeck":0}]
```

But the deletion with this "instanceTime" gives an error:

```
DELETE FROM tododb.taskstable WHERE (instanceTime like '2018-02-10T15:07:34.000Z' AND email like 'admin@gmail.com' );
errError: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect datetime value: '2018-02-10T15:07:34.000Z' for column 'instanceTime' at row 1
```

Why is the formating "2018-02-10T14:19:29.000Z" this way?
When I am using:

```
DELETE FROM taskstable
WHERE (instanceTime  like "2018-02-10 14:19:29" AND  email like "admin@gmail.com");
```

everything works just fine

Comment: String date format in MySQL is not configurable. There's also no auto-detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did 2 things to fix this problem.

1. Change DB time field to int(11) and inserted new value with the current UNIX timestamp instead-

> insert into taskstable
>           values (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),"to call mom","admin@gmail.com",false);

The UNIX timestamp is a lot easier to manage since it is just a countdown.

2. I changed the view formatting in the HTML page, to show UNIX time as the desired human-readable version, this way:

> {{t.instanceTime * 1000 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}

Not exactly what I asked, but I found this a lot easier.